# How to export/import .dll that uses third party .lib files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I have 2 projects, **A** and **B**. **B** is a WinRT/WinUI app.

Project **A** uses third party static libraries **C,D,E...**

I can build project **A** and I get **A.lib**, **A.dll** files as output.

Problem comes when I try to include **A** in my **B**.

In **B** I configure the *include directories* to point to **A** header files, *Linker-> Input* to point to **A.lib** and *Linker->Additional library directories* to the A.lib directory. I manually copy paste *A.dll* in **B** output folder.

When trying to build **B** I get following error in console output:

```
 \A\XY.h(10,10)  fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'namespaceC/blah.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file Generated Files\XamlTypeInfo.g.cpp)
```

Strange thing is when I build **A** the file A\XY.h compiles ok.
Any help is welcome...

Comment: I can only recommend to use CMake, since you won't have a happy life with all that visual studio native click here click there BS, which also changes with any path change or VS version change.

Comment: Add to include directories the parent of *namespaceC*. Or look at the *A* settings and copy from there.

Comment: The problem is A uses C,D,E... so a lot of .libs. If I have to include C,D,E into B than there is no point in A, A exists so that B doesn't have to include 3 different libs...

Comment: @LordTrololo As far as I'm concerned, every exe project project needs to introduce direct and indirect lib dependent libraries at the same time. You need to include C,D,E into B. If there are more projects, I suggest you try to use [Share or reuse Visual Studio project settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/create-reusable-property-configurations?view=msvc-160).Add A's project settings to B. And then link A.